# The mod has failed to load correctly: null

Tags: minecraft-forge

When I tested my mod with Minecraft 1.15.2, the forge showed: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgt4f.png)

And the latest.log like this: [log](https://github.com/Meteor-code257/model-1.15.2/blob/main/latest.log)

The source code here: [source](https://github.com/Meteor-code257/model-1.15.2)

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.
Who can help me?

Comment: Start by asking a good question. This is not one. Take the [tour] and see [ask]

Comment: Please paste the relavant code into the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Hint: the important part of latest.log is lines 74-76.